# Pass a tex value to lua in context

Tags: luatex, context

I have the following code

```
\startluacode
company = context.env("company")
patch_file = "public/" .. company .. "/patch-english.json"
\stopluacode
```

where I pass the company value via command line `context --arguments=company=mycompany mydoc.tex`

This does obviously not work. How can I get the variable from the command line into lua code?

Comment: It's in `environment.arguments` I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `environment.argument` to query the command line arguments.

```
\starttext

\startluacode
company = environment.argument("company")
context("company = " .. company)
\stopluacode

\stoptext
```

```
context --company=mycompany test.tex
```

[image]

If you do not want to use Lua, you can try

```
\starttext

company = \env{company}

\stoptext
```

```
context --arguments=company=mycompany test.tex
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it for general tex variables?

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Reza What do you mean with “general tex variables”? You can of course use `context --company='\def\company{mycompany}' test.tex` if that is what you want. Documentation I don't know. I usually discover stuff by following the mailing list.

Comment: @Reza I think I found what you were looking for. See updated answer.